# How to recognize phone number autofill input in shouldCharactersChangeIn (UITextField)

Tags: ios, swift

so I wrote my own custom phone number formatter (for UITextField). The problem is that I call it in the function shouldCharactersChangeIn, and for some reason it can't detect any of the characters that are being filled in when using autofill. Here is the code for my phone number formatter:

```
extension UITextField {
    func phoneNumberValidation(shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String, phoneNumber: String = "(XXX) XXX-XXXX", replacementCharacter: Character = "X") {
        // phoneNumber should have base replacement character X (you can customize it
        let maxLength = phoneNumber.count
        if maxLength == 0 {
            return
        }
        var currentPosition = 0
         if let selectedRange = self.selectedTextRange {
             currentPosition = self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
         }
         var restrictedString = string
        
         if string.count > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: " 0123456789-()").inverted
             if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: disallowedCharacterSet) != nil {
                 restrictedString = ""
                 currentPosition -= 1
             }
                        
        }
        var removeCharactersAt: [[Any]] = []
        let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(replacementCharacter))
        var removeText = phoneNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: charSet)
        removeText = removeText.components(separatedBy: charSet).joined()
        
        
        for i in 0..<removeText.count {
            let text = phoneNumber

            let range: Range<String.Index> = text.range(of: String(removeText.charAt(i)))!
            let index: Int = text.distance(from: text.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            removeCharactersAt.append([removeText.charAt(i), index])
        }
        
        var tempRemoveArray = [Int]()
        for i in 0..<(removeCharactersAt.count - 1) {
            if (removeCharactersAt[i][1] as! Int + 1) == removeCharactersAt[i+1][1] as! Int {
                let newString: String = String(removeCharactersAt[i][0] as! Character)
                let newString1: String = String(removeCharactersAt[i + 1][0] as! Character)
                removeCharactersAt[i][0] = newString + newString1
                tempRemoveArray.append(i + 1)
                
            }
        }
        
        for i in 0..<tempRemoveArray.count {
            removeCharactersAt.remove(at: tempRemoveArray[i])
        }
        

        var currentText = NSString(string: self.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: restrictedString)
        print(currentText)
        for i in 0..<removeText.count {
            let character: String = String(removeText.charAt(i))
            let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: character)
            if currentText.rangeOfCharacter(from: charset) != nil {
                currentPosition -= 1
            }
        }
        
        
        let delCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: removeText)
        currentText = currentText.trimmingCharacters(in: delCharSet)
        currentText = currentText.components(separatedBy: delCharSet).joined()
        
        for i in 0..<removeCharactersAt.count {
            let index: Int = removeCharactersAt[i][1] as! Int
            let replacementCharactertemp = removeCharactersAt[i][0]
            var replacementCharacter: String
            var replacementTemp = replacementCharactertemp as? String
            if replacementTemp == nil {
                replacementTemp = String(replacementCharactertemp as! Character)
            }
            
            if replacementTemp!.count > 1 {
                replacementCharacter = String(replacementCharactertemp as! String)
            } else {
                replacementCharacter = String(replacementCharactertemp as! Character)
            }
            
            if currentText.count > index {
                if !(range.length == 1 && range.location == (index + replacementCharacter.count) && currentText.count < (index + replacementCharacter.count)) {
                    for i in 0..<replacementCharacter.count {
                        currentText.insert(replacementCharacter.charAt(i), at: currentText.index(currentText.startIndex, offsetBy: index + i))
                        currentPosition += 1
                    }
                }
                for i in 0..<replacementCharacter.count {
                    if range.location == (index + i) && range.length == 1 {
                        currentPosition -= 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        for i in 0..<removeCharactersAt.count {
            let index: Int = removeCharactersAt[i][1] as! Int
            let replacementCharactertemp = removeCharactersAt[i][0]
            var replacementCharacter: String
            var replacementTemp = replacementCharactertemp as? String
            if replacementTemp == nil {
                replacementTemp = String(replacementCharactertemp as! Character)
            }
            
            if replacementTemp!.count > 1 {
                replacementCharacter = String(replacementCharactertemp as! String)
            } else {
                replacementCharacter = String(replacementCharactertemp as! Character)
            }
            
            if range.location == index && currentText.count > (index + replacementCharacter.count) && range.length != 1{
            currentPosition += 1
            }
        }
        
        if currentText.count > maxLength {
            currentText = String(currentText.prefix(maxLength))
        }
        
        if(string == ""){
            currentPosition = currentPosition - 1
        }   else {
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1
        }
        
        self.text = currentText
        
        if let newPosition = self.position(from: self.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentPosition) {
            print(newPosition)
            self.selectedTextRange = self.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm calling it:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        if textField.tag == 4 || textField.tag == 5 || textField.tag == 6 {
            var phoneNumber = ""
            if countryId == 1 {
                phoneNumber = "XXXX-XXXXXX"
            } else if countryId == 2 {
                phoneNumber = "(XXX) XXX-XXXX"
            } else {
                phoneNumber = ""
                (textField as! FloatingLabel).displayErrorMessage(message: "Please select a country first")
            }
            
            print(textField)
            print(range)
            print(string)
            
            textField.phoneNumberValidation(shouldChangeCharactersIn: range, replacementString: string, phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    }
    return false
}
```

How can I detect what characters are being filled in when the user autofills. Currently, autofill doesn't do anything and the textfield just stays blank. I tried printing the textField and string and range, but when I press the autofill tab nothing shows up in the string or range or textField. It's like I pressed the key that did absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When autofill happens, the delegate method indeed does not get called.

Since `UITextField` is the subclass of `UIControl`, you can listen to control events.

`UITextField` sends `.editingChanged` control event for both typing from keyboard and making autofill.

Add your event listener like this:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And then, implement `func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField)` method.